# How to change an applet's life cycle on javacard?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I have uploaded a HelloWorld.cap applet on smartcard and when I use `gpj -list` command the card return below output :

```
    D:\gpj>java -jar gpj.jar -list
    Found terminals: [PC/SC terminal ACS CCID USB Reader 0]
    Found card in terminal: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
    ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00
     .
     .
     .

    AID: A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00                       |........|        ISD LC: 1 P
    R: 0x9E

    AID: 11 22 33 44 55 66                             |."3DUf|          App LC: 7 P
    R: 0x00

    AID: 11 22 33 44 55                                |."3DU|           Exe LC: 1 P
    R: 0x00
```

As you see the life cycle of my applet is 7 and life cycle of its package is 7. And for both of package and applet privilege is 0x00 . how I can change them?(PR and LC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change **LC** (Life Cycle) use **Set-Status** APDUs:

for example :

**OP_READY** To **INITIALIZED** : `80 F0 P1 07 |Lc| AID`

**INITIALIZED** To **SECURED** :  `80 F0 P1 0F |Lc| AID`

**P1** = `40` : For Applications (Including SSDs)

**P1** = `80` : For ISD

And in order to change **PR** (Privilege) you should add `-priv` parameter to `gpj` install command.

for example : `gpj -load helloWorld.cap - install -priv 0x04`

Answer (score 3):

Applet privileges and life cycle states are described in GlobalPlatform Card Specification, you can download it from http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp
It is a long document and not particularly easy to read, but I really recommend going through it if you plan to work with smart cards.

It explains how to assign privileges for applets (mostly at installation time) and how to transition through the different life cycle states. For example, it says that your Hello World applet is already in SELECTABLE state, so it can only transition to LOCKED or be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/javacard1-139251.html#_Lifecycle_of_a

according to that, it is not something you can change after all, is it?

Comment: Sometimes you can, depending on the initial state, transition rules and so on.